# applicationWillTerminate not called

Tags: macos, cocoa, application-close

I implemented applicationWillTerminate method, but it's never called

```
-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:self];
    NSLog(@"EOP");
}
```

How to execute some code before application close?

Thanks

Comment: It isn't, there's UIApplication from iOS Dev libraries and here's Mac OS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just added

```
-(BOOL) applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *) sender{
return YES;
}
```

Now applicationWillTerminate invokes

Comment: If this changes it, then perhaps the app wasn't actually closing? You were just closing all the windows of the app?

Comment: Most likely you're right. But now app closes: I got that I needed

Comment: It isn't possible to close an application; that verb doesn't go with that noun. And yes, an application ordinarily does not automatically quit when the user closes its last window; you must opt into that. Actually quitting the application with the Quit command will always trigger `applicationWillTerminate:` (assuming nothing, such as a confirmation alert, gets in the way). An alternative introduced in Lion is Automatic Termination, which is lazier and pretends the app is still running; see the docs.

Comment: How does this even work when you defined function as returning nothing but you return bool?

Comment: Of cause it's misprint) fixed

Comment: This just tells your app that it should quit automatically when there is no more opened window. It is not really related to the 'applicationWillTerminate never called' problem

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1:

Set the **Application can be killed immediately** to **NO** in the project info ( `NSSupportsSuddenTermination` key ).
The `applicationWillTerminate` function will then be called before the application quits.

Solution 2:

If you need to be able to cancel the termination, then you should rather override the `applicationShouldTerminate` function

```
func applicationShouldTerminate(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSApplication.TerminateReply {
    // Do some stuff before quitting for good
    return .terminateNow
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please set a key (`UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`) in your plist to `YES`.

> Key    : UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend
>   Type  : Boolean
>   Value :YES

Comment: This question is about osx not ios, notice the `NSApplication` in the question?